# DataNucleus: How do I automatically perform actions when commiting a transaction?

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

Consider having an application using DataNucleus with the following persistence structure:

You have a class that has two attributes like *created* (Date) and *lastUpdate* (Date): How do you automatically fill those attributes with the appropriate values when an object of this class is going to be committed?
Appropriate values would be setting both, *created* and *lastUpdate* to the current time when an object is inserted into the database and just updating *lastUpdate* when it has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself now.

You need to create an [InstanceLifecycleListener](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/listener/InstanceLifecycleListener.html)...

```
public class BasicEntityLifecycleListener implements StoreLifecycleListener {

    public void postStore(InstanceLifecycleEvent evt) {
    }

    public void preStore(InstanceLifecycleEvent evt) {
        if((PersistenceCapable)evt.getSource() instanceof BasicEntity) {
            BasicEntity obj = (BasicEntity)evt.getSource();
            Date now = new Date();
            if(JDOHelper.isNew(obj))
                obj.setCreated(now);
            obj.setLastUpdate(now);
        }
    }
}
```

and then register it within you PersistenceManager...

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
pm.addInstanceLifecycleListener(new BasicEntityLifecycleListener(), null);
```

I found the solution in the [DataNucleus Access Plaftorm manual](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/datanucleus-accessplatform.pdf) which I didn't have recognized until now. The online manual seems a bit complex to me.

Comment: Do you know a way to trigger any InstanceLifecycleEvent ? I need to execute the LoadLifecycleListener when i do a pm.getObjectById(...), but, i assume that, depending on cache conditions, the object my not be loaded from the database, and so, the listener is not triggered... is there a way to do it manually?